# jQuery UI date picker makes problems with mobile devices

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, jquery-ui-datepicker

We are using [this jQuery UI date picker wrapper](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date) which is working fine for the Desktop version of the site.

But we do have a huge problem when it comes to a mobile device. Then when I click on the input field, the datepicker shows up and additionally the mobile keyboard appears as well which uses half of the screen.

Currently our directive looks like this (CoffeeScript):

```
"use strict"

angular.module("theapp").directive "datePicker", ->
  restrict: 'EA'
  scope:
    model: '='
    name: '@'
    required: '@'
    options: '='
  template: '<input type="text" ui-date="dateOptions" ng-model="model" ng-required="{{ required }}">'
  replace: true
  link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
    scope.required ?= false

    scope.dateOptions =
      dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"
      yearRange: "1900:-0"
      changeYear: true
      changeMonth: true
      regional: "de"
    _.extend(scope.dateOptions, scope.options)
```

What I tried so far:

- Bluring the input field as soon as it gets focus. *Result:* The mobile keyboard flickers twice.
- Changing the type from text to button. *Result:* It works just fine on a Desktop, but not on a mobile device. Maybe I'm doing something wrong here.

Anyone knows a good solution how to fix that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `readonly="readonly"` to the input and the keyboard won't pop up anymore on mobiel devices (tested on iPhone only):

```
<input type="text" id="date_picker" readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: That is just a nice and easy solution. The only problem now is that there is no blur-action so the date picker would disappear. But I guess I can fix that. If you have an idea, please let me know